# Transpiling ES6 in a Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules, laravel-mix

I was asked to make some developments in a Laravel 7 web app. (I'm new to Laravel)

I wish to use the more modern JS syntax, but in order to support the older browsers, I need to transpile the code, and I'm having trouble with that.

I have 2 different files/modules and in a third one, I need both of them.

I will just post the code so you can have a better grasp. (***code edited to be shorter***)

**package.json**

```
 "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^4.43.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.0-beta.6",
}
```

**SERVICE 1**

```
function foo(id) {
    const URL = someUrl;
    return fetch(URL, { method: 'GET' })
        .then(response  => response.json())
        .then(json      => json);
}
   
export const serviceOne = {
    foo: foo
}
```

**SERVICE 2**

```
function clearSelectpicker(selectpicker) {
    selectpicker
        .html('')
        .selectpicker('refresh');
}
    
export const domService = {
    clearSelectpicker: clearSelectpicker
}
```

**MODULE THAT REQUIRES THE ABOVE SERVICES**

```
import { serviceDom }   from '/resources/js/services/dom.service.js';
import { serviceOne }   from '/resources/js/services/one.service.js';

async function laod(cod) {
    serviceOne.something();
}

async function find(id) {
    serviceDom().bla();
}
```

**webpack.mix.js**

```
mix.js('resources/js/services/dom.service.js', 'public/assets/js/services/dom.service.js');
mix.js('resources/js/services/one.service.js', 'public/assets/js/services/one.service.js');
mix.js('resources/js/main.js', 'public/assets/js/main.js');
```

Then I run ***npm run dev***

ERROR in ./resources/js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/resources/js/services/one.service.js'

ERROR in ./resources/js/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/resources/js/services/dom.service.js'

Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

**For those with similar problems**

```
import { serviceDom }   from '/resources/js/services/dom.service.js';
import { serviceOne }   from '/resources/js/services/one.service.js';
```

to

```
import { serviceDom }   from '../services/dom.service.js';
import { serviceOne }   from '../services/one.service.js';
```